# SQL- What is the lead_id , account_id and the number of days between lead created_date and the account created_date

Tags: sql, subquery, union, datediff

For each lead associated with an account, what is the lead_id, account_id, and the number of days between the lead created_date and the account created_date?

```
lead_id    created_date     industry
INT DATE    VARCHAR (25)
```

e.g. 2345566    2019-01-25  sales

```
account_id    created_date  lead_id
INTEGER DATE (YYYY-MM-DD)   INTEGER
```

e.g 34345564 e.g. 2019-03-14    123152

I have tried this

```
Select
Distinct Lead_id,
Distinct Account_id
Datediff(days,l.created_date,a.created_date)
From
Lead l
Join 
Account a
On a.lead_id= l.lead_id
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `distinct` for this.  Assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
Select Lead_id, Account_id
       Datediff(days, l.created_date, a.created_date)
From Lead l Join 
     Account a
     On a.lead_id = l.lead_id;
```